Keeps on getting 'For ECS deployment group, blueGreenDeploymentConfiguration must be specified' error when creating cloudformation stack
I have successfully launched an ecs cluster with a single service attached to task definition(containing multiple containers), facing behind an ELB (seperate target groups and listener rules for each container) using Cloudformation stack. Now i wanted to include code pipeline to the stack with in_place deployment(not blue/green). Below is the resource definitions.
past question link - Task definition contains multiple containers listening on different ports using one ECS service and ALB but some containers are not running
  ECSCodeDeployApplication:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: MyECSApplication
      ComputePlatform: ECS

ECSCodeDeployDeploymentGroup:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref ECSCodeDeployApplication
      DeploymentGroupName: MyECSDeploymentGroup
      DeploymentConfigName: CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce
      DeploymentStyle: 
        DeploymentType: IN_PLACE
        DeploymentOption: WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
      ServiceRoleArn: !GetAtt CodeDeployServiceRole.Arn ## <your-codedeploy-service-role-arn>
      LoadBalancerInfo:
          TargetGroupInfoList:
            - Name: devops-Posts-5CKSXC5HCCOB
            - Name: devops-Threa-FHPCL8KYJTZZ, 
            - Name: devops-Users-OPQF72DP5CMQ]
          # TargetGroupPairInfoList:
      ECSServices:
        - ClusterName: DevopsCluster ## <your-ecs-cluster-name>
          ServiceName: devops-project-Service-ItAlogJgBhkV ##<your-ecs-service-name>

CodePipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: MyECSPipeline
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn
      # ArtifactStore:
      #   Type: S3
      #   Location: <your-s3-bucket-for-artifacts>
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: SourceAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: GitHub
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              Configuration:
                Owner: ##<your-github-username>
                Repo:  ##<your-github-repo-name>
                Branch: main
                OAuthToken:  ##<your-github-oauth-token>
        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: BuildAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: CodeBuild
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProject
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: DeployAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: '1'
                Provider: CodeDeploy
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: BuildOutput
              Configuration:
                ApplicationName: !Ref ECSCodeDeployApplication
                DeploymentGroupName: !Ref ECSCodeDeployDeploymentGroup

but I am getting this error from aws For ECS deployment group, blueGreenDeploymentConfiguration must be specified (Service: AmazonCodeDeploy; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidBlueGreenDeploymentConfigurationException; Request ID: e98cee30-640f-4199-9003-108d4e0ca04d; Proxy: null)
